# Differences between constructor syntax and assignment syntax for primitive type initialisation

Tags: c++

Reading some code written by a coworker I stumbled on the use of constructor syntax to initialize a primitive type variable. Ie something like below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    // initialized using assignement syntax (copy initialisation)
    int titi = 20;
    cout << "titi=" << titi << "\n"; // got 20 in titi, it works

    // initialized using constructor syntax (direct initialization)
    int toto(10);
    cout << "toto=" << toto << "\n"; // got 10 in toto, it works
}
```

My natural tendency would be to stick with the assignement syntax, as it is the historical one and it's a no brainer, and there is obvious compatibility issues (consructor syntax won't qualify as valid C).

Still I wonder if there is any other non obvious difference between the two syntax ? If they are actually meaning the same thing ? And what are the pros and cons of one or the other form considering for instance future maintenance/code evolution issues or readability issues ?

Comment: One is copy-initialization and the other is direct-initialization.

Comment: Initialisation and assignment : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350155/initialisation-and-assignment)

Comment: @p1rox, There's no assignment here.

Comment: Two kind of initialization. By the way, copy initialization is not assignment.

Comment: @lulyon: what difference do you see between copy and assignement (beside the word used)? I always called `=` operator assignment operator and it is supposed to change the l-value isn't it ? When using `=` to define reference I call that aliasing, but may be I'm also wrong and I should call that assignment ?

Comment: @kriss The obvious difference is that assignment is only done after initialization, while copy initialization is Simultaneously done with variable(or object) initailization. Assignment is done by perator=, while copy initialization is not necessarily so.

Comment: @lulyon: OK, I believe I get the point. Use `copy constructor` wording when speaking about assignment to a previously uninitialized object (which is allowed to call directly constructor) ; reserve use of `assignment` wording only when changing a previously initialized object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple types such as `int`, there is no difference.  For
class types, what you call "constructor syntax" is known as
direct initialization, and what you call "assignment syntax" as
copy initialization.  You cannot use copy initialization unless
the class supports copy, so the tendency is to prefer direct
initialization (with the caveat that then one must worry about
the most vexing parse problem).  Some people then argue in favor
of the direct initialization syntax everywhere, on grounds of
homogeneity: use the same format everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor syntax is useful when dealing with templates because you don't know whether the type will be a primitive type or a class.

Comment: while working with templates is there a guarantee that all classes will have copy constructors?

Comment: @thomas In what sense?  You generally impose constraints on the template argument types, like CopyConstructable and Assignable (if you need those properties); it's almost impossible to write a template that can work with absolutely any class a user could write.  (But note that direct initialization doesn't require a copy constructor.)

Comment: good point, but as the code I'm speaking about is not a template, I guess I have no reason to do that.