# C++ Constructor initialisation member variables

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

So I've seen two different ways of initialising an object's member variable in the constructor:

```
MyObject(int var1, int var2) :
    mMemberOne(var1),
    mMemberTwo(var2)
{

}
```

and (the way I've always done it previously):

```
MyObject(int var1, int var2)
{
    mMemberOne = var1;
    mMemberTwo = var2;
}
```

Is there any benefit of one over the other? I ask on here because I don't know the correct terms to search for with Google. I just get pages about how to initialise an object or other basic principles.

Thanks

Comment: The first one creates the members initalised to the values you passed, the second initialises your members possibly to garbage and then assigns the value, the first method is more efficient and should be the convention

Comment: `initialization-lists` is the keyword you should look for.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350155/initialisation-and-assignment

Comment: and this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/in-this-specific-case-is-there-a-difference-between-using-a-member-initializer