# Difference in pointer declaration?

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between these two declarations?Can someone explain me?

```
int *ptr=&num;
```

and

```
int *ptr;
ptr= &num;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialisation and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350155/initialisation-and-assignment)

Comment: It would indeed be a duplicate if the answers to the proposed duplicate were not focused on C++...

Comment: And as the difference can disturb beginners, I'm not sure that this question really deserves being downvoted

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference meaning wise. In the first case, you are declaring the pointer variable and initializing it right away. (`&num` is initializer here).

In the second case the pointer is declared and it then contains the garbage value (considering they are of automatic storage duration) until you assign it the address of `num` - in between these two if you use it then it's UB. In the first case you kill this chance of using unintiialized pointer variable's value.

Note that, in the second case `ptr= &num;` is not part of declaration. It is assignment statement. The declaration was simply that `int *ptr`.

You can check this rule to get an idea of declaration: From [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7)

```
      declaration:
             declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
             static_assert-declaration
      declaration-specifiers:
             storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
             type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
             type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt
             function-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
             alignment-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
      init-declarator-list:
              init-declarator
              init-declarator-list , init-declarator
      init-declarator:
              declarator
              declarator = initializer  <-------
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a semantic difference, even if both end in same result: you have declared a pointer to `int` (`ptr`) and have it point to a variable (`num`).

Now for the difference:

```
int *ptr=&num;
```

*declares* a pointer (it is even a *definition*) and uses an *initialization* to set its initial value, while:

```
int *ptr;
ptr= &num;
```

first *declares* a pointer, and then *assigns* a value to it.

The specific differences come from there:

- an initialization is valid at file scope, while an assignation is not
- if the pointer were static, the assignement would be repeated on each pass, while the initialization let the variable keep its value:

  ```
     int *foo() {
         static int num[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
         static int ptr = &num;              // one time only initialization
         return ptr++;
     }
     int main() {
         for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
             printf("%d ", *foo());
         }
         return 0;
     }
  ```

  will print `1 2 3 4 5`, but if we write:

  ```
     int *foo() {
         static int num[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
         static int ptr;
         ptr = &num;              // assignment on each call
         return ptr++;
     ...
  ```

  the result will be `1 1 1 1 1`
- you can initialize a `const` variable

  ```
      int * const ptr = &num;
  ```

  while you cannot assign to it

  ```
      int * const ptr;
      ptr = &num;            // syntax error
  ```
- you can initialize an array, while you cannot assign to it
- may be others...

Answer (score 0):

To me, the big difference is that it looks funny at first.

For conventional, non-pointer variables, we can write, for example, either

```
int num = 5;
```

or

```
int num;
num = 5;
```

The thing we declare (`num`) is exactly the same as the thing we assign.

But in the case of pointer declarations, there's that pesky extra `*`.  This pattern causes some beginning programmers to attempt to write the following incorrect code.  Since we can have

```
int *ptr = &num;
```

why can't we rearrange it as

```
int *ptr;
*ptr = &num;           /* XXX looks superficially right, but WRONG */
```

In this case, following the previous pattern, we're trying to make the thing we declare (`*ptr`) the same as the thing we assign.

But this is wrong, that's not the way pointer declarations work in C.  The thing we're declaring is not `*ptr`.  The thing we are declaring is just `ptr`, which has type `int *`, or pointer to `int`.

For this reason, some people like to write pointer declarations differently:

```
int* ptr;
ptr = &num;
```

Now it's more obvious that the thing we're declaring (`ptr`) is the same as the thing we're assigning.

The only problem here comes if we try to declare two pointers on the same line:

```
int* ptr1, ptr2;       /* probably WRONG: ptr2 is *not* a pointer */
```

But of course this does not actually declare `ptr2` to be a pointer.

We could also make things more clear using typedefs:

```
typedef int *intptr;
```

followed by either

```
intptr ptr = &num;
```

or

```
intptr ptr;
ptr = &num;
```

And in this case declaring two pointers on the same line works properly:

```
intptr ptr1, ptr2;     /* both ptr1 and ptr2 are pointers */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *ptr;        // It’s a pointer variable.
ptr=&num;        // ptr holds address of num.
int * ptr=&num;  // Address of num is held by pointer ptr.
```

When you use `*` in front of any variable, it’s not mandatory to use again. 
That’s why you declared as `ptr=&num`.

Answer (score 0):

int *ptr=& num; statement declares a variable "ptr" of pointer type and initializes it with the address of variable "num" at the same time.

Whereas the statements int *ptr; *ptr=& num; first declare a pointer type variable which currently holds garbage value.

The value, i.e. the address of "num" variable is assigned to the pointer variable in the next statement.