# My question is about how to overload the assignment operator for assigning a string to an object

Tags: c++, string, class, operator-overloading

My teacher gave us a homework and just gave the following information:

"This code block in main must be compiled and run."

```
String s1, s2 = "Ahmet", s3 = "Nalbant";
s1 = s2 + " " + s3;
cout << s1;
```

For this problem,   I know that I have to create a class whose name is "String" . To implement the first row I have to overload the assignment operator . Actually I overloaded it but the compiler still giving this error " conversion from 'const char [8]' to non-scalar type 'String' requested" .
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class String
{
   private:
   char * Name ;

   public:
    String() ;
    ~String() ;
    void operator= (char* Name) ; // To overload Assignment operator.
    String operator+ (const String &Obj) ; // To overload Addition operator.
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& Out,const String& B) ; // To overload ostream operator.

};

String::String()
{
  Name  = NULL ;
}

String::~String()
{
    cout << "program has  finished successfully\n" ;
}

void String::operator= (char* Name)
{
    strcpy(this -> Name, Name) ;
}

String String::operator+ (const String &Obj)
{
    String String_Object ;
    String_Object.Name = strcat( this ->Name, Obj.Name) ;
    return String_Object ;
}

/* ostream& operator<< (ostream& Out,const char* & Name)
   {
   }
*/

int main()
{
    String S1, S2 = "Ahmet", S3 = "Nalbant" ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Could you please help me and correct "void String::operator= (char* Name)"
function.

Comment: You need to allocate storage of sufficient size to copy `name` into. This will apply all through your code.

Comment: Its surprising, but this: `S2 = "Ahmet"` doesn't call `operator=` it calls the `String(const char* s)` constructor, which doesn't exist in your solution.

Comment: `typedef std::string String` is one way. Then you get to go to the pub.

Comment: To add to Mr. Fox (the fantastic): [SO: Initialisation and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350222/7478597).

Comment: Btw. your assignment operator is done a bit unlucky. It should return a reference to `this`: `String& operator=(const char *Name) { /* discard old contents */ /* store new contents (by copy of Name) */ return *this; }`

Comment: "how to overload the assignment operator for assigning a string to an object" - `String& operator=(const std::string& Name);` for strings. `String& operator=(const char* Name);` for literals/C--style strings.  `String& operator=(const String& Name);` for a copy-assignment operator.