# C++ variable list Initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

So here are piece of 2 code

#1

```
int i=0, j=0;

for (i=0,j=0; i<=5; i++, j++)
    {
        cout<<i<<"  "<<j<<endl;
    }
```

#2

```
int i{0}, j{0};

for (i{0},j{0}; i<=5; i++, j++)
    {
        cout<<i<<"  "<<j<<endl;
    }
```

[image: Build Messages]

1st code allows me to replace the value inside `for` loop that was stored in `i` and `j`.
But in the code #2 (in which I used c++11 list initialization) it shows some errors. But this works :

```
int i{0}, j{0};

for (i,j; i<=5; i++, j++)
    {
        cout<<i<<"  "<<j<<endl;
    }
```

Why can't I replace them inside loop?
What is the correct way for #2 and how should I Proceed?

Comment: The correct way to do #2 is to use #1.  related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350155/initialisation-and-assignment

Comment: Initialization is for initializing a variable. After that you can only assign to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List initialization, as the name suggests, is for the *initialization* of a variable. Initialization can only happen once, *initially*. You can assign to a variable, but list initialization is not for assignment (and yes, I know some types do allow assignment from braced-init-lists, but `int` isn't one of them).

So the correct way to do #2 is to not do it.